# Does Chern-Simons theory have any time dependence?

Tags: time, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Chern-Simons theory is of topological nature. If we put it on a compact 3-manifold this should yield a topological invariant. As any TQFT it should not have any time dependence, in other words, the notion of time is not defined.

**My question is if this is correct or not.** If we put the theory on compact $M_3$ then in principle we should be able to deform it such that it looks (locally)a tube with initial and final regions $M_3$ and in the middle stretched like $\mathbb{R} \times M_2$. Another choice would be $S^1 \times M_2$. **Is there any notion of time periodic or not?**

Comment: If you put the theory on a *compact* $M_3$ I would be very disturbed if it can be deformed to $\mathbb{R}\times M_2$ since that's not compact. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Yes, because I made a small typo. Let me correct the question

Comment: Not all manifolds are tori, you get slightly more manifolds by allowing some twisting before regluing the ends of the cylinder, these are called [mapping tori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_torus). Still, only very small part of compact 3D manifolds are mapping tori, most are hyperbolic, see [geometrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_geometry_of_S2_.C3.97_R) You can certainly consider CS theory on a torus, or even a cylinder, [Dunne](http://cds.cern.ch/record/379553/files/9902115.pdf) explicitly treats it as a theory on 2+1 spacetime.

Comment: But cylinder or torus is 2d. We need to put CS on a compact 3 manifold. What is then the notion of time if all the dimensions are compact? Physically time has to be non-compact.

Comment: And note that Dunne always considers non-compact manifolds of the form 2+1. I am interested in the case where we have a compact manifold without boundary, so closed. What is the notion of time there?